# How do you get doc with value in array of arrays in firebase with .where()

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have my firebase with a few nested arrays, but i'm wanting to find all documents that contain that document ID (as a test/example)

wanting to get basically: doc.where('clients.doc', 'array-contains', docID);

however this didn't work, wanting to find a better solution or an answer to my so far answer which is the way that i have organised the database is the problem.

Comment: people that down vote with no back-up and answer to help are the bane of stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query that nested array structure. The only array query operation is an `array-contains`, but that only works for top-level arrays, or arrays at a known path.

So to allow this query, you'll have to add an additional top-level array field with the client document IDs, and then query on that.